# Android error praising XML unbound prefix

Tags: android

Aapt:error praising xml unbound prefix
i have following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate android:interpolator="0x10a0005" android:duration="0x10e0001" android:fromYDelta="0.0" android:toYDelta="50%p" />
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific on the problem that you have. It seems unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your question is not clear, please be little more specific about the issues you are facing,
Secondly, one problem that I see with your code is, it misses the xlmns import. Try this, but am not sure if this will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="0x10e0001"
    android:fromYDelta="0.0"
    android:interpolator="0x10a0005"
    android:toYDelta="50%p" />
```